# Jenkins Master with High CPU Usage

Tags: java, jenkins, development

I have a Jenkins master that takes around **600%** of CPU usage. It causes load average of 50 and makes Jenkins crash several times.

I tried to remove several plugins and clean the workspace in order to have less jobs (I don't have many jobs - approximately 50).

I am using Jenkins 2.38 but this was also happening with Jenkins 1.6.

Comment: Does your Jenkins consume 600% with no jobs runnning or you run 50 jobs at the same time?

Comment: Our master doesn't do anything, the slaves do all the work. But even with no jobs jobs at all (including the slaves) the CPU usage is around 600%.